# Optimal configuration for a RAID + ZFS

Tags: raid, zfs

What would be the optimal configuration for a server using raid and where I want to place ZFS only?

I heard that while using ZFS would be better not to use at all the raid controller , is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZFS needs to have full access to individual disk devices in order to work optimally.

If one uses a RAID controller, ZFS cannot access individual disks and much of ZFS benefits are not achieved.

The optimal setup is to pass-through the individual disks via the RAID controller.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was searching for. but not sure how to configure the machine without the drive controller

Comment: maybe implementing hba?

Comment: some old server require that you need to create each disk as a single device, some work like without configuration and some others needs a look at the manual ;)

Comment: @djdomi eheh you're right